# How to copy an object in Java

Tags: java

I'm making my own sort of anythink, which implements Comparable interface. Algorithm looks fine, but `Comparable a = list.get(i);` is a link as i guess, but i need a copy of this object. I cant use `list.get(i).copy()`, because it is undefined for Comparable.

```
private static void sortIncrease(ArrayList<Comparable> list) {
    int i, j;

    for (i = 1; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Comparable a = list.get(i);

        for (j = i - 1 ; j >= 0 ; j = j - 1) {
            int cmpResult = a.compareTo(list.get(j));

            if (cmpResult < 0) {
                list.set(j + 1, list.get(j));
            } else {
                list.set(j+1, a);
                break;
            }
        }
    }       
}
```

Comment: Why do you need a copy of the object? If that's a sorting algorithm, there's no need for that.

Comment: Right, you normally don't copy the object, you copy the reference.  Also `Comparable` is normally parameterized.  E.g. `Comparable<Integer>`.  Don't use raw types.

Comment: I cant parametrize it, because i dont really know, what it is. It could be a string, or an int, or smth else. @markspace

Comment: Then use a wildcard.  `Comparable<?>`

Comment: @Kayaman it doesnt work, because "a" is a link

Comment: Start [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html). And please, those are references, not "links".

Comment: Why does it matter if "a" is a reference?

Comment: @IvanSalosin No, you're absolutely wrong. You want to sort the references inside the list, you don't want to copy objects.

Comment: @markspace if i type private static void sortDecrease(ArrayList<Comparable<?>> list) , eclipse says, i still cant use Object.copy() method

Comment: Also, there is no `Object.copy()` method.

Comment: @Kayaman on  8 7 6 this algorithm gives 8 8 8

Comment: That has nothing to do with references/objects. It has everything to do with your code being broken. Copying objects won't fix it, your logic is wrong. Hint: you need a temporary variable.

Comment: @Kayaman as i understand, A is refer to 7, then 7 becomes 8 and now A refers to 8, and now my list is 8 8 8

Comment: You're using ArrayList.set(), but not removing the original item.  An arraylist allows duplicates.

Comment: Is it nesseccary to remove original item? next step i'd like to replace it with "A" or ArrayList[j]

Comment: @Kayaman the OP doesn't need a temporary variable. `a` already serves that purpose. This looks like an Insertion Sort algorithm that's coded incorrectly. There's no need to constantly swap consecutive variables in the Insertion Sort algorithm.

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou yeah, it is Insertion. But i cant figure out, where is a mistake?

Comment: @KlitosKyriacou You're right, it looked like a bubble sort with a quick look. However, copying objects is still not required.

Comment: @Kayaman and if i dont copy list[j], how can i insert it, when figure out where to?

Comment: You can copy the reference, you still don't need to copy the object. So forget about looking for `copy()` or `clone()`.

Comment: @Kayaman oh, it looks like i'm an idiot. Maybe it is because 00:30 in my city and its time to sleep. I found mistake, it was in if-else construction. I had to list.set(j+1, a); in outher 'for', not in inner. Thanks for your time, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, it happens.

Answer (score -1):

I can suggest you a "bad way" to do it, create your own clone method.
You can:

-take as input the parameters of the other Comparable and clone them into your object

-create a method that provide your parameters and insert it in a constructor later.